# Hide and reveal segments in PDF output of LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Constructing a dynamic PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/constructing-a-dynamic-pdf)

I want to include the solution of a math problem under its statement, but not in full view. I would rather have a page segment that can be brought to view by activating a button and made hidden when not needed. One solution is to use `tooltips`. However this option covers portions of the page and appears as a different format. I would rather have a page segment that drops down and appears as mostly like the continuation of top portion of the original page. This is to be in the context of a basic PDFLaTeX output for viewing on a monitor (not for presentation). What would you suggest?

Comment: Does [Constructing a dynamic PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/constructing-a-dynamic-pdf) help?

Comment: Can LaTeX write things to different layers?

Comment: @Canageek, [apparently yes](http://www.texample.net/weblog/2008/nov/02/creating-pdf-layers/)