# Showing hyperrefs (figures, references ...) in a pop-up when hovering over

Tags: hyperref, fancytooltips, tooltips

As I am currently writing my thesis, I would like to show figures, tables, refs ou equations corresponding to an hyperref when hoverring over the hyperlink with the mouse inside the produced PDF as in:
[image]

Note: I don't know why but the mouse does not appear on screenshots. It is respectively on **1987** and **2** of **figure 2(b)**.

I looked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key) where solutions are described. However, Is there any solution that does not require the use of an external script, and is pure latex ? I would imagine a package that enables the preview for all hyperrefs ?

EDIT:

Thanks to @AlexG comments, I managed to get this working for bibliographic entries.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% usage: \autociteTip{<bib key>}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\autociteTip}[1]{%
  \autocite{#1}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \tooltip**[black!0]{|}{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\fullcite{#1}}}%
  }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I have 3 questions remaining :

1. The pop up appears when the mouse is over the left of the clickable reference, where I'd like it to appear when being over the clickable link (boxed by default in green)
2. When using `\autocite` with multiple references, only one pop up appears containing all references. Is there anyway to separate it into different ones ? It is somewhat linked to the previous question.

[image]

3. How can I recover what has been displayed into `equation` and `figure` environment ? I.e how can I define the `eqref` so that it displays the related equation ? Same for the figure.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that first paragraph. I have no idea what it is you are after.

Comment: One of the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19673) mentions two tooltip packages.  Not sure they are workable (the answer also mentions ConTeXt), but possibly worth checking.

Comment: @daleif see edit with image !

Comment: @barbare beeton the fancytoolip is used as one of the solutions in the link I gave. However, you gave to create the tooltips yourself. Or at leat a macro for all bib entry, one for figures, etc...  All of this are old packages/solutions, I would have imagined something more automatic by now !

Comment: Look at this method which does not use external scripts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111932

Comment: An updated version of the `\tooltip` command used therein is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186

Comment: I should be able to merge the two. The hardest seems to make a good tooltip with a figure + caption ... I'll try and let you know. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I4; doing fine with your current code, but I still have a few questions. Please see edits of the question above !